# Check if windows password is correct with batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

How can you check if a Windows password is correct with batch. Using runas you could check if you get an error after typing your password but I want to know how to do it automatically by adding the password into the batch file (I know its not secure and I know you can save credentials with runas). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please note, this is a new user. If you downvote this question, at least have the courtesy to leave a comment why you downvoted it and how Henry should improve it.

Comment: I can't see why the question is downvoted. It's a perfectly valid question, and he states that he knows it's not secure

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what OS, user access, and how your machine is configured, you could issue a net use to the machine itself on a particular drive letter.

Eg:

```
Net use U: /delete /y
Net use U: \\machinename\c$ /user:machinename\username password
```

You could check if the U: drive ended up mapped to verify it worked.

This is not a good idea security-wise and also may not work on systems with simple file sharing enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you have permissions to create/delete windows scheduled tasks, you could always use SCHTASKS:

```
SCHTASKS /CREATE /RU "Username" /RP "Password" /TN CREDCHECK /TR NOTEPAD /SC ONSTART
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (ECHO Valid) ELSE (ECHO Invalid)
SCHTASKS /DELETE /TN CREDCHECK /F
```

There's probably better values for the /TR and /SC parameters, but you get the idea